# How to compare randomly generated number with user entered number at run time in C?

Tags: c

I am making Bubble game in c where randomly some numbers are generating on the console window and user need to enter that numbers appearing on the screen or console window and I need to compare that user input and random generated number and make that number invisible from the screen.

I have used rand() function in c and for user input I have used getch() function and i have tried every type conversion but not getting the solution yet.

```
void main() {
char temp1 = 0;
char temp = 0;
temp1 = rand()%10;
   temp = getch();
   if(temp == temp1)
   printf("ok");
  }
```

I want to compare randomly generated value and user input at run time and input given by the user by seeing on console's number is equal i want to exit.

Comment: `getch();` is not inputing a digit in the numeric range `0`..`9` but in the character range `'0'` .. `'9'`. So try `temp = getch() - '0'`;

Comment: yup! its is working thank You, but I didn't get why you subtracted '0' from getch().

Comment: Or `temp1 = '0' + rand() % 10;` looks better. And you should be using `int` not `char`.

Answer (score 0):

A digit character has a character code value `'0'` to `'9'` (in the ASCII character set 0x30 to 0x39 or 48 to 57 decimal), while `rand() % 10` has integer value 0 to 9.

By adding the character code `'0'` (48) to the random number you will generate a random character code `'0'` to `'9'`.

```
int main()
{
    char temp1 = rand() % 10 + '0' ;
    char temp = getch() ;

    if( temp == temp1 )
    {
        printf("ok");
    }

    return 0 ;
}
```

Alternatively if you subtract `'0'` from the  input *character* you will transform digit characters to their corresponding 0 to 9 integer values (and other characters to some other value).

Comment: thank you so much.I got it.